# User Send me XSS into my site by Contact form 7

Tags: xss, contact-form-7

Today i receive an email from user send XSS like :

```
Name : fglfnglkmvbklmv

Title : iofdjgiosjfiosdhuet

Email : oifdjgiodfjgiodfji@fgiuk.fhju

Message : <script>alert("XSS");</script>﻿
```

How can save my site from this ?

Comment: Did the code got executed?

Comment: no got executed

Comment: If so, you're already protected. Just make sure you're escaping it whever you output it to some html pages.

Answer (score 0):

CF7 is pretty secure and it does do a pretty good job of filtering out XSS injection however I would also recommend using fail-2-ban and/or security plugins to tighten things up if you already haven't.

On most of them you can whitelist your IP so that you can make changes to code via the backend with out getting blocked.